# What is the QMessageBox::aboutQt equivalent in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Is there an equivalent of `QMessageBox::aboutQt` which can be used in QML? I didn't find anything suitable in the `QtQuick.Dialogs` module (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickdialogs-index.html).

Comment: I didn't understand. `QMessageBox::about ` is a simple Dialog with the `OK` button. you can have that in QML too.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html#details

Comment: Right sorry - my bad. I meant QMessageBox::aboutQt not QMessageBox::about. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest match of `QMessageBox::about` with QML would be [`MessageDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html) setup like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

MessageDialog {
    title: "Your title"
    icon: StandardIcon.Information
    text: "Your text"
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```

As for `QMessageBox::aboutQt`, according to [this topic](https://forum.qt.io/topic/52686/solved-qml-equivalent-for-qapp-aboutqt/3), in the Qt forum, there is no QML equivalent and it is better to invoke `qApp->aboutQt`:

> reading the docs seems there's no aboutQt for QML.

> probably better to invoke standard qApp->aboutQt from C++ class.